# Найти пароль LINUX

Tags: linux

Linux устанавливал человек, который сейчас вне доступа. Система требует пароль, как решить проблему попроще. Я не очень разбираюсь. Пожалуйста помогите, заранее благодарен.

Comment: toor наверняка подойдёт

Answer (score 4):

Найти вы его никак не найдёте (если только этот человек его на бумажке не записал:)), но сменить можно загрузившись в однопользовательском режиме и выполнив команду passwd.
Вот инструкция как загрузиться в однопользовательском режиме: http://www.k-max.name/linux/sbros-parolya-root/ (раздел "Восстановление пароля root").
Возможно так же в Вашей ОС, в меню выбора операционной системы для загрузки (то, которое появляется непосредственно перед тем, как начнёт грузиться операционка), есть пункт "Recovery mode". В таком случае - выберите его. Если никакого меню вы не видите - нажмите Shift после загрузки BIOS.

Если у вас есть LiveCD/LiveUSB с каким-нибудь дистрибутивом Linux - вы так же можете загрузить его, смонтировать корневой раздел Вашего винчестера и вручную отредактировать файлы etc/shadow и etc/shadow- как указано здесь - [http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/пустой_пароль](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)